# Write Serializable objects to file - Google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In standard java , I can use FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream to write serializable objects to a file, but they are not supported in google cloud storage. Is there anyway to write serializable object to a file when using cloud storage ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize the object to byte array and than use [AppEngine cloud storage API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/) to store the data in the cloud storage.